# Create or Overwrite image with PHP

Tags: php

I have a form with a text input to allow user insert the URL of an image and submit the form to upload the image to server. So the image is converted to PNG, rename with a hash and saved on server dir `images/`
Thats the code to upload:

```
   if (isset($_POST["cover"])) {
        imagepng(imagecreatefromstring(file_get_contents($_POST["cover"])), "images/".$hash.".png");
   }
```

That works ok, the problem is when user try to update the image from a new URL. It does not work, and i get no visible errors.

The form to update image have an input with `value` of actual converted and hashed image on server. If the user modify the input URL and submit the update form, it suposed to overwrite the current image on server. But that is not happening.[EDIT, ITS SOLVED. I WAS USING THE WRONG $VARIABLE FOR HASH.]

Now im having the cache issue. How can i show the updated image after submitting the form without having to clean the browser cache??

Comment: Your update code should work. The browser may be displaying a cached copy of the image.

Comment: @Barmar No, its not cache. I already cleaned and reloaded. The server image is not being affected by the update form.

Comment: How are you setting `$hash` in the update script?

Comment: Are you sure you're overwriting the actual file with the correct $hash name? Is it being stored in a DB or something?

Comment: @Barmar and Pjack wow thank you! i was using the wrong $variable for hash! Thanks a lot man for openning my eyes, its working now. but with the "cache" issue. You know how can i solve that?

Comment: See Jm Verastigue's answer regarding cache solutions.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about just using the wrong variable name.

Comment: Please ask a new question if the subject has changed significantly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try forcing the browser to clear the cache

```
header( 'Expires: Sat, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT' ); 
header( 'Last-Modified: ' . gmdate( 'D, d M Y H:i:s' ) . ' GMT' ); 
header( 'Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate' ); 
header( 'Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0', false ); 
header( 'Pragma: no-cache' );
```

or append a timestamp on the image parameter

```
<img src="image.png?<?php echo(time());?>" />
```

Comment: The main question was solved, but now i have that cache issue. Can you give me more details on how to implement your answwer? Thank you.

Comment: The `header()` solution only works if you're using a PHP script to send the images, not if you're just accessing them directly as files.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17332910/how-to-update-a-image-on-server-via-form-and-display-it-after-submission