# How to update a image on server via form and display it after submission?

Tags: php

I have a form with a text input to allow user insert the URL of an image and submit the form to upload the image to server. So the image is converted to PNG, rename with a hash and saved on server dir `images/`
Thats the code to upload:

```
   if (isset($_POST["cover"])) {
        imagepng(imagecreatefromstring(file_get_contents($_POST["cover"])), "images/".$hash.".png");
   }
```

That works ok, the problem is when user try to update the image from a new URL.

The form to update image have an input with `value` of actual converted and hashed image on server. If the user modify the input URL and submit the update form, it will overwrite the image on server.

Now im having the cache issue. How can i show the updated image after submitting the form without having to clean the browser cache??

The details page: `index.php?page=details`

User click on update, the update page is loaded `index.php?page=edit`

User submit the form and the inserted data is saved and load back to the details `index.php?page=details` wich the image in question is displayed.

Comment: So you are keeping the hashed name for the new image too?

Comment: @Pjack yes, the name must remain intact. because that hash is attached to other files.

Comment: how is the image displayed on the page? Might need to see more code? What happens when the form is submitted?

Comment: @Pjack see my question again, see if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Just append `?<?=time()?>` to the end of the `src` attribute and it will generate a timestamp which, hopefully, make the browser request the image again and ignore the cache.

You can look to .htaccess too, define a FilesMatch directive that sends headers to enforce the browser to no cache at all.

```
<FilesMatch "\.(png|jpg)$">
    FileETag None
    <IfModule mod_headers.c>
         Header unset ETag
         Header set Cache-Control "max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
         Header set Pragma "no-cache"
         Header set Expires "Wed, 11 Jan 1984 05:00:00 GMT"
    </IfModule>
</FilesMatch>
```

I hope the answer was helpful.

Comment: Im still trying to implement that time apend. only to clarify the url must be `images/".$hash.".png?=".time()`or `images/".$hash.".png?".=time()` ?

Comment: `images/".$hash.".png?".time()` the = operator in this case serves as a shorthand for echo.